# How do I predict the future closing price of stock after training and testing?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, linear-regression

I am trying to do multivariate time series forecasting using linear regression model.

In the below code I first split the data in 80-20 ratio for training and testing.

Then I train the model and use the model to predict using test and compute the relevant performance metrics of the model.

```
    # Split data into testing and training sets
    X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(df[['EMA_10']], df[['close']], test_size=.2)
    
    # Create Regression Model
    model = LinearRegression()
    # Train the model
    model.fit(X_train, y_train)
    # Use model to make predictions
    y_pred = model.predict(X_test)
    
    # Printout relevant metrics
    print("Model Coefficients:", model.coef_)
    print("Mean Absolute Error:", mean_absolute_error(y_test, y_pred))
    print("Coefficient of Determination:", r2_score(y_test, y_pred))
```

Now how do I predict the next i.e. future value?

Comment: Just put values of X that represent future times into the x vector when you call `predict()`

Comment: @ThePhoton but I have only used EMA and close price. And I do not know future EMA values.

Comment: Then you need to train your model to predict the value for dates later than the input data you give it, rather than just to "predict" the price at a time when the price is already available.

Comment: For example, each row of `xtrain` includes EMA and prices for some set of 10 days and `ytrain` has the price for the 11th day in each row.

Answer (score 1):

To predict unseen `y`, you can simply use `.predict(<new x here>)`.

However, why are you using linear regression to tackle the time series problem? It makes the data lose the time dimension. It's important to note that when performing time series forecasting, it's generally a good idea to use a model specifically designed for time series data, such as an autoregressive model (e.g., ARIMA) or advanced DL (e.g., RNN). These kinds of models are able to account for the temporal dependencies that are present in time series data, which can help improve the accuracy of the forecasts.

There are many good resources for that, such as,

https://machinelearningmastery.com/arima-for-time-series-forecasting-with-python/

https://towardsdatascience.com/temporal-loops-intro-to-recurrent-neural-networks-for-time-series-forecasting-in-python-b0398963dc1f